# How to display a popup after clicking an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a simple popup window on clicking over the image that I have put up on my webpage. I don't see the popup on clicking the image. Can anyone help me sort out this problem? Following is the code that I have right now:

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

```css
.popup {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
    .popup .popuptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 160px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 8px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -80px;
    }
    
    
    .popup .popuptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }
      
      .popup .show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
        animation: fadeIn 1s
    }
    
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity: 1;}
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity:1 ;}
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
       <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
       <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Why the hell you are using `bottom: 125%;`? Btw you have no `body` tag.

Comment: I removed the bottom: 125% and now I see the popup, but now its just being displayed on the top no matter where I click on the image. I want the popup to show near the point of click. Can you tell me how do I do that?

Comment: STYLE tag should be nested in HEAD tag, and your codeshould have BODY tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view popup where mouse click on screen

```js
function myFunction(e) {

  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
  $("#myPopup").css({
    left: x
  });
  $("#myPopup").css({
    top: y
  });
  $("#myPopup").show();

}
```

```css
.popuptext {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 400px;
  padding: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  background: green;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
  <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction(event)" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much for your help. I get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is just badly implemented:

change this:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
   <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction();" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">       
<div class="popup"  style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

The image was inside the popup and the myFunction was clalled from the popup. I just put the image outside the popup and assigned the onlick event to the image.

everything else works.

## EDIT for coordinates of the popup

I've changed your CSS a bit for this:

```
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
.popup {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

in css i removed the position of the .popup and the bottom: 125% thing.

in your html i added and event to the call of myfunction:

```
<img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction(event);" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">       
<div class="popup"  style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

And finally the javascript to add the popup on coordinates of the click event:

```
function myFunction(event) {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    popup.style.top = event.clientY-40 + "px";
    popup.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Now I see the popup on the bottom of the page no matter where on the image I click. I want the popup to show near the point of click. Can you tell me how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JSFiddle that should help you, the popup is linked to a button but can easily be changed to an image.

```
<button id="button"></button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ede46hcm/

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
function myFunction() {
      
       $("#myPopup").toggle("show");
      
    }
```

```css
 .popuptext
                {
                    display: none;
                    color: white;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 100px;
                    left: 400px;
                    padding: 50px;
                    border: solid 1px #ddd;
                    background: green;
                    width: 10%;
                }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup"  style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
             <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction()" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
             <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I implemented your code and it shows the popup. But now I want the popup to show near the point of click. Can you tell me how do I do that?

Comment: add another answer try it